# stack a small circle container in circle avatar flutter

Tags: flutter

How to add a circle container in the circle avatar like in the photo using stack?

[image: Screenshot]

Here's my current code:

```dart
CircleAvatar(
    radius: 30,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
    collection[index].profile!.avatar!))
```

Comment: You might want to try [Badge](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Badge-class.html) or [badges](https://pub.dev/packages/badges)

Answer (score 1):

you can do this using  **Stack**, **Positioned** and **BoxDecoration**

```
          Container(
            color: Colors.blue,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  width: 50,
                  height: 50,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: const Color(0xff7c94b6),
                    image: const DecorationImage(
                      image: NetworkImage('http://i.imgur.com/QSev0hg.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50.0)),
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 2.0),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  right: 0,
                  bottom: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 20,
                    height: 20,
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
```